# Binding To Array Values SwiftUI iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

I'm struggling to find how to bind an array value to a Toggle view in SwiftUI.

Lets says I have an observabled class with a Boolean array:

```swift
class TestClass: ObservabledObject {
    @Published var onStates: [Bool] = [true, false, true]
    static let shared = TestClass()
}
```

and in a View I have

```swift
...
Toggle(isOn: TestClass.shared.$onStates[0]) { // Throws error 'Referenceing subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires wrapped value of type '[Bool]'
    Text("Example Toggle")
}
```

Why is it seemingly impossible to bind a particular array value to the toggle button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need observer in view for observable object, so fixed variant is

```
@StateObject var vm = TestClass.shared   // << observer

var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: $vm.onStates[0]) { // << binding via observer
        Text("Example Toggle")
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I completely just missed putting the StateObject in there.

Comment: hello. does this work the same way if i want to bind my data with @ObsevableObject?